# Why does .NET Core 3 app crash on Webview usage?

Tags: c#, webview, .net-core

I migrated a WPF app to .NET Core 3 with no issues expect that if I launch a WPF form containing a [WebView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView/5.1.1) I get this (inner) exception:

```
MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find the resource "Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.DesignerUI.resources" among the resources "Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.DesignerUI.resources" embedded in the assembly "Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView", nor among the resources in any satellite assemblies for the specified culture. Perhaps the resources were embedded with an incorrect name.
```

I created a sample repo to reproduce [here](https://github.com/korneliuscode/webviewissue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use WebView in version 5.1.1

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView" Version="5.1.1" />`

On Nuget page you can see that this version supports .NET Framework 4.6.2, so it's not compatible with .NET Core 3.

I see that there is a 6.0.0-preview version and those support .NET Core 3, so you should try with it, but it is a preview version, so bugs can be present.